# Java ME Runnable object takes up memory although not made an instance yet

Tags: java-me

I am facing a strange problem with memory in Java ME.

here is a part of my code:

```
int variable=1;

while (true) {
  if (variable==2) {
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);         
    MyCanvas mc = new MyCanvas(this);   // MyCanvas is a runnable object
    mcT = new Thread(mc);    // new thread for MyCanvas
    mc.repaint();
    display.setCurrent(mc);  
    mcT.start();  // run thread
    }

  if (variable==1) {
    // Do some other stuff
    }
  }
```

The problem is that although still the `variable` is set to `1`, so it does not come through the `if (variable==2)` condition the program consumes 300kB more memory than when I delete the code after condition `if (variable==2)`.

As far as I know the code should by executed and the objects shall be created only when I set variable to value `2`. But it consumes the memory also when the code after condition "if (variable==2)" is not executed.

Why does this happen?

Comment: how do you find out about memory consumption? are you testing it in emulator?

Comment: @gnat he probably prints `Runtime.freeMemory()`. Do you have many classes and resources? Do you use proguard?

Comment: You might initialize other objects in other  areas of your code

Comment: My guess is that, when you're not referring to MyCanvas, then maybe it gets obfuscated out? But as soon as there's a reference to it, it'll be kept. 300kb does sound like a lot though.